# Automate clicking of button on program launch

Tags: windows, keyboard, automation, mouse-click

I know how to auto start a program when Windows starts up (by creating a shortcut in the Startup folder), but when the program starts there is a button titled "Proceed" which needs to be clicked. Can this (clicking) be done by coding or software automatically?

Comment: Can we all get the specific application?

Comment: Check out [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)/AutoIt.

Comment: You could write a program to do it, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the window you are talking about is User Account Control promting you to confirm the program that was just run by startup.

You can [disable](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off) User Account Control and the prompt won't appear.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in creating your own (AKA don't want to chance installing other people's stuff on your box), here's an example in C#:

```
public class PushAButton
{
        public const int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
        public const int WM_NOTIFY = 0x004E;

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int FindWindow(string strClassName, string strWindowName);
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern System.Int32 SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [System.STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            /// The following code toggles the Shuffle option in Windows Media Player
            int iHandle = FindWindow("WMPlayerApp", "Windows Media Player");
            /// use spy++ to find the command. 0x499A in decimal is printed out when you press Control H in Windows Media Player.
            SendMessage(iHandle, WM_COMMAND, 0x0000499A, 0x00000000);
        }
    }
```

As this is just an example, you'll have to find the actual window title and executable name and the actual message number you want to send to the window with Spy++ (available with Visual Studio).

Then, simply automatically start up your button-presser program right after the other one has begun.

Links that helped me create this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/02/542115.aspx

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessage.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294%28VS.85%29.aspx

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/813190-how-do-i-get-handle-currently-focused-window

Answer (score -1):

You should use a macro recording tool. 
Here's a free one:

http://roomdl.com/quick-macro/

```
Quick Macro (QMacro) is an intelligent software to record, replay and edit keyboard and mouse macros.
```